# Declarative base not collecting tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy to define a schema, and alembic to manage migrations. My file structure looks like this:

```
db
|----model
|    |------ __init__.py
|    |------ tableone.py
|
|----assorted alembic files...
```

My model's __init__.py uses a declarative base to collect all the table defitions:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

import db.model.tableone
```

And then my table's definition looks like this, tableone.py:

```
from ..model import Base
from sqlalchemy import (Column, Integer)

class TableOne(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    column_one = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
```

Alembic seems to understand this structure and can successfully generate migrations. However, if in other code, such as my tests, I import my Base, it has no tables. Here is an interactive example from inside the `db` directory with the directory containing `db` added to my `PYTHONPATH`:

```
import model
model.Base.metadata.tables
>>>> immutabledict({})
```

Why doesn't the `Base`'s metadata have any tables? I've read through the sqlalchemy docs and I see that sometimes declarative base's are bound to an engine, but it looks like this is for creating tables, which I don't want to do. I only want to see the metadata, but it's empty

Comment: Where are you relative to your file structure when you can execute `import model` in the interpreter? I'm just trying to replicate but if I execute that in an interpreter above the `db` directory I get `No module named 'model'`. From inside `db` directory I get `No module named 'db'`. My theory is that due to your relative import in `tableone.py` importing `db.models.Base` and in the interpreter, `import model`, you are dealing with 2 distinct instances of `Base`, and the one you are inspecting is not the one the tables are defined upon.

Comment: Hi @SuperShoot, thanks for looking. The above example is inside the `db` directory, with the parent directory added to my `PYTHONPATH` (it's part of a larger module). I also suspect it has to do with different instances of `Base`, but I can't quite figure out how to fix it, and alembic seems to have no trouble constructing migrations out of it

Comment: How do you import your metadata into `alembic/env.py`?

Comment: `from db.model import Base`
`target_metadata = Base.metadata`